# Selected item by default on TabBar is not getting highlighted

Tags: swift, xcode, tabbarcontroller

I'm using a TabBar with two items. I'm creating it on a .xib file and setting the ViewControllers programatically. I can choose the default VC with:

```
    selectedIndex = 0
```

The problem now is the tabBar not highlighting the selected item icon.

I set the VC's on TabBarController's viewDidLoad():

```
    let firstViewController = FirstViewController(nibName: "FirstViewController", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.viewControllers = [firstViewController, secondViewController]
```

And here's the code to create the items on each VC:

```
    let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "First", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "firstImage"), selectedImage: nil)
    self.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
```

Not just the selected index by default is not highlighting, sometimes It shows only one of them until I tap on the tabBar.

EDIT:

I add three images.

**First** one is taken just after loading the VC. NO item has been tapped, programatically selected index 0 and VC is presented as expected.

**Second** one is after performing a tap on the second item, it shows but both are not highlighted.

**Third** one is after doing one more tap, now, no matter which one is pressed, the highlighting works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT 2:

I added a video:

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWdmi.jpg)

Comment: Where do you assign `selectedImage` to `tabbarItem`?

Comment: I'm not assigning it. I've tried and it changes the image when it's selected, and then goes back to the other one when unselected. But the highlighting issue still remains.

Comment: Try `tabbar.selectedIndex = 0` ? In `TabBarController` class write `self.selectedIndex = 0`. Do not make another `tabbarItem` as you have already setup in `xib`.

Comment: self.selectedIndex = 0 is on My tabBarController class already. I didn't understand actually what you're trying to say sorry.

Comment: @108g Check my answer below

Comment: @108g Where did you write the code `selectedIndex = Int` ?

Comment: @TheTiger on UITabBarController's viewDidLoad(), (obviously I have written selectedIndex = 0 not Int)

Comment: @108g I know. Just wanted to know the place where you wrote this.

Comment: @TheTiger Monty's answer helped. I think the problem was creating the Tab Items on each VC so TabBar didn't had a clue of what Icon the second VC had until it loaded for first time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the images to selectedIndex tabBar item accordingly like below

```
  let myTabBarItem1 = (self.tabBar.items?[0])! as UITabBarItem
  myTabBarItem1.image = UIImage(named: "Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
  myTabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected ")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
  myTabBarItem1.title = "First"


  let myTabBarItem2 = (self.tabBar.items?[1])! as UITabBarItem
  myTabBarItem2.image = UIImage(named: "Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
  myTabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
  myTabBarItem2.title = "Second"
```

Comment: Ok so it worked. I just had to remove the selectedImage lines cause I dont really want to change it. If i just specify the image the tabBar itself uses the highlighted icon when selected and a "disabled" version of it when not selected. I don't know if there's a "cleaner" way to do it but so far it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set image and selected image to `tabBarItem`, See the following code.

```
  let myTabBarItem1 = (self.tabBar.items?[0])! as UITabBarItem
  myTabBarItem1.image = UIImage(named: "Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
  myTabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected ")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
  myTabBarItem1.title = "First"


  let myTabBarItem2 = (self.tabBar.items?[1])! as UITabBarItem
  myTabBarItem2.image = UIImage(named: "Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
  myTabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
  myTabBarItem2.title = "Second"

    for tabBarItem in tabBar.items! {
        tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
    }
```